# How to add recylerview2 inside recylerview1 by clicking listitem of recyclerview1?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-adapter

I have image like this for example:

Recylerview2 inside Recylerview1

[image: img]
In this case:

If I click on the number 1 of list item, then recylerview2 will appear below a number 1

So my question is:

How can i do that? and this is my code.

Ive this code inside onBindViewHolder inside adapter.

```
    fItemsHolder.mLinearReply.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (item.getName2() != null) {
        fItemsHolder.mHiddenComment.setText(item.getName2()+": "+item.getComment2());
        fItemsHolder.feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        int jComment = Integer.parseInt(item.getJumlahComment().toString());
        if( jComment > 0){
            fItemsHolder.mHiddenComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    commentItems = new ArrayList<CommentModel>();
                    adapter = new NoteCommentListAdapter(mContext, commentItems);
                    mRecyclerView = new RecyclerView(mContext);
                    getListViewComments(item.getUserid(), item.getId(),fItemsHolder,i, commentItems, adapter, mRecyclerView);
                    commentItems = new ArrayList<CommentModel>();
                    adapter = new NoteCommentListAdapter(mContext, commentItems);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        fItemsHolder.mHiddenComment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fItemsHolder.mLinearHiddenComment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

And this is my asynctask:

```
private void getListViewComments(final String userid, String id_note,final feedItemsHolder feedItemsHolder, int i, final List<CommentModel> commentItems, final NoteCommentListAdapter adapter, final RecyclerView mRecyclerView) {
    class ambilComment extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;
        com.android.personalRoom.asynctask.profileSaveDescription profileSaveDescription = new profileSaveDescription();
        String result = "";
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            feedItemsHolder.mLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            feedItemsHolder.mHiddenComment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            feedItemsHolder.mLinearHiddenComment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            feedItemsHolder.mLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
            data.put("userid", params[0]);
            data.put("id_note", params[1]);
            String result = profileSaveDescription.sendPostRequest(URL_LIST_VIEW_COMMENT,data);
            return  result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;
            if(s.equals(null)){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Internet Problem.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.w("notakomen", "notakomen: "+s);
            }else{
                Log.w("notakomen", "notakomen: "+s);
                try{
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s);
                    String id_note = json.getString("id_note");

                    dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id_comment = c.getString("id_comment");
                        String uid = c.getString("userid");
                        String profile_name = c.getString("profile_name");
                        String profile_photo = c.getString("profile_photo");
                        String amount_of_like = c.getString("amount_of_like");
                        String amount_of_dislike = c.getString("amount_of_dislike");
                        String amount_of_comment = c.getString("amount_of_comment");
                        String content_comment = c.getString("content_comment");
                        String tgl_comment = c.getString("tgl_comment");
                        String parent_id = c.getString("parent_id");

                        Log.e(TAG, "id_comment: " + id_comment
                                + ", uid: " + uid
                                + ", profile_name: " + profile_name
                                + ", profile_photo: " + profile_photo
                                + ", amount_of_comment: " + amount_of_comment
                                + ", tgl_comment: " + tgl_comment);

                        CommentModel citem = new CommentModel();
                        citem.setId_note(id_note);
                        citem.setId_comment(id_comment);
                        citem.setUserid(uid);
                        citem.setProfileName(profile_name);
                        String pPhoto = c.isNull("profile_photo") ? null : c.getString("profile_photo");
                        citem.setProfile_photo(pPhoto);
                        citem.setJumlahLove(amount_of_like);
                        citem.setJumlahNix(amount_of_dislike);
                        citem.setJumlahComment(amount_of_comment);
                        citem.setContent_comment(content_comment);
                        citem.setTimeStamp(tgl_comment);
                        String prntID = c.isNull("parent_id") ? null : c.getString("parent_id");
                        citem.setParent_id(prntID);

                        citem.setLevel(level);
                        commentItems.add(citem);

                        feedItemsHolder.mNameReply.setText(profile_name);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.w("getListNotesComment", "exception");
                }
                feedItemsHolder.mLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                feedItemsHolder.mLinearReply.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
           /* iH.mHiddenComment.setText("");*/
        }
}
    ambilComment ru = new ambilComment();
    ru.execute(userid, id_note);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using an Expandable listview with a recycler view inside?

Comment: Now my question is, can expandablelistview be scrolled inside CollapsingToolbarLayout? because when im using recylerview, it can be scrolled inside CollapsingToolbarLayout. Like this http://imgur.com/R8kQvg1 @MalithLakshan

Answer (score 1):

Try using this library: [android-advancedrecyclerview](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview)

Check this [example](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview/tree/master/example/src/main/java/com/h6ah4i/android/example/advrecyclerview/demo_e_basic) on how to use expandable recyclerview using this lib.

To use it, add the lib to your project by adding a dependency for it in the `gradle.build` file as:

```
dependencies {
    compile ('com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.9.1@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
}
```